# Fitting exponential nls in R

Tags: r, statistics, nls, non-linear-regression

I am trying to fit a line of best fit to some data. From the look of it it's a negative exponential curve. I have managed to use the `nls` function to find a second order polynomial fit, but when I try to fit an exponential problems occur....

When I type in the following:

```
exponential.model = nls( prcol ~  I(p1*exp(p2*agecol) + p3), start = c(p1=1, p2=-1, p3=1))
summary(exponential.model)
```

R outputs a message:

> Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
>        Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model

I have spent an awful long time playing around with different initial parameters but I either get this message or another saying that the matrix is singular....

I am trying to fit a line on price against age (graph is attached to link below)

[click to see graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwduJ.jpg)

Comment: Get rid of the `I()` in your formula - this isn't a linear model. And you could probably get rid of `p3` - seems like its interpretation would be "the price of an infinitely old car".

Comment: I still get the same error message after applying your recommendations

Comment: Can you post some data, maybe `dput(head(your_data, 10))`? And why aren't you using the `data` argument to `nls`? You're not `attach`ing are you? Don't attach, it can cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as the op is non-responsive and the problem is not reproducible.